# How to handle dependencies when writing characterization tests

Tags: test-automation

I am currently working on a codebase that is full of objects that are 3000+ lines long and have at least 20 dependencies each, and I'm about to try covering them with characterization tests before I start refactoring them, but I'm not sure how to deal with the dependencies they have.

at first I thought "if I don't mock these out, it'll be an integration test", so I mocked them out for a smaller function, with about 6 dependencies, and gave it a try.

The tests cover the code, but they just look like bloated unit tests. I didn't even need snapshots for most of them because I could just check that the value returned was one of my mocks. They also give me the impression that I'm missing something about the concept.

Should I not mock out anything? should I just mock out the database calls? Am I missing something else? I'm a bit confused tbh and would love it if someone who has worked with approval testing could tell me how they do it

thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong writing characterization tests as integration tests.  If your test setup is getting bloated and you have to adhere to existing code you don't have a lot of options.  Common ways to approach this are to change the boundaries where you are testing or find an acceptable balance of mocks (or find common setup patterns and make some utility functions, but that's just test refactoring)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> objects that are 3000+ lines long and have at least 20 dependencies each

The primary thing to remember here: **you have an essentially untestable codebase**. You can't go from that to a set of perfect looking tests in one step - quite possibly your first set of tests are ugly, a bit hacky and cross all sorts of boundaries between unit tests, functional tests and everything else.

But they're tests, and they let you increase your confidence when you do any refactorings - and then as you refactor, you can break down those monster classes into more mangeable chunks, and then you can rework your tests to be in a better shape as well.

I would as always recommend Feathers' *Working Effectively with Legacy Code* in this kind of scenario - I've found the techniques he describes for how to "inject" tests into not necessarily well-formed codebases invaluable over the years.

Comment: yeah, I remember reading that book a lifetime ago... gonna have to pick it up again.
relative to mocks though, should I mock anything? everything? nothing? does the answer vary from scenario to scenario. I talking specifically about characterization tests, which coincidentally are from that book

Comment: Michael Feathers came up with the term "characterization test". I don't have a personal copy, but I'm pretty sure that it's talked about in Working Effectively with Legacy Code and this answer does a good job of summarizing, especially the first paragraph - your characterization tests are going to cross boundaries that wouldn't need to be crossed to test systems designed for testability. As you refactor, you may also be able to refactor your characterization tests and replace them by tests that are more appropriately isolated.

Comment: @ThomasOwens [Feathers has an article on the subject](https://michaelfeathers.silvrback.com/characterization-testing) - but to re-re-emphasise the point, that page itself says "The hardest part is breaking dependencies around a piece of code well enough to be able to exercise it in a test harness."

Comment: tyvm for the help! could you add the link to the article to your answer?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think I read that article before. I interpreted that as meaning writing characterization tests that keep the dependencies in place is easier than doing the refactoring to actually make the code testable through other means (like good unit and integration tests). Which is not to say that writing characterization tests is easy, because it may be difficult. But the refactoring could be more difficult, but at least you'll be able to tell if you've broken the system if you have those characterization tests in place.